# choose a value with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table in cells A1:E5, I would like to randomly select a value out of cells which are non blank.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: PLease let me know if you need more explanation. i have been using choose( randbetween( manualy select the cells with value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365 you could use:
`=LET(a,TOCOL(A1:E5,1),INDEX(a,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(a))))`

Or `=LET(a,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:E5,1)),INDEX(a,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(a))))`
If you want each number to have the same chance, regardless the times being repeated in the range.

The idea is: TOCOL with ignore blanks argument (`1`) will filter the range for values only. If you rand between 1 and the number of (unique) values, you can index that array of non-blank values and return the random row's value within that array.

Comment: yes i have 365. this works as well. wish i could tick mark both.

Comment: @Mohit - they're almost identical. Tick whichever you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same but different. I saw BigBen posted during me answering, so he was first. Mine has a twist about the uniques. Not sure what you prefered. You can still upvote his answer as I did (tick arrow up).

Comment: One alternative approach: `=LET(x,TOCOL(A1:E5,1),INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(MIN(x),MAX(x))))`

Comment: That's a nice alternative to the unique version I posted

Answer (score 1):

One option using `TOCOL`, `INDEX` and `RANDBETWEEN`:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A1:E5,1),INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(x))))
```

[image]